# how to disable the innodb_force_recovery option in magento

Tags: server

i am gettting the error as in this link :

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/72116/magento-site-sqlstatehy000-general-error-1030-got-error-28-from-storage-engi#72116

so i got some solution here :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16002461/magento-site-down-due-to-mysql-error-general-error-1030-got-error-1-from-stora

i want to know how to disable the innodb_force_recovery option as mentioned in the link

please help me to find solution

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Settings for InnoDB can be set in the servers `my.cnf`. Usually the file is located under `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

Add something like this to the file

```
# innodb
innodb_force_recovery = 0
```

Comment: thanks for reply, this text : innodb_force_recovery = 0 is not there in this file : my.cnf , can i add to that file ? in phpmyadmin, this "innodb_force_recovery " value is "0".

Comment: you can add it but if PHPMyAdmin indicates it's 0 it's already set to that value

Comment: yes, please check here : http://prntscr.com/7l5fnt than is there any other solution according to this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16002461/magento-site-down-due-to-mysql-error-general-error-1030-got-error-1-from-stora

Comment: Well you could check if the disk is full, or at least the part reserved for MySQL files. And check permissions on the InnoDB file but I can't imagine someone would change those

Comment: Nope, means you're not root prob. I would advice to contact the hosting provider

Comment: we are using aws server, [vps]

Comment: In that case you might want to find a sysadmin or post the question on serverfault for example. They're better in servers.